# Rails 3 LIKE query raises exception when using a double colon and a dot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

In rails 3.0.0, the following query works fine:

```
Author.where("name LIKE :input",{:input => "#{params[:q]}%"}).includes(:books).order('created_at')
```

However, when I input as search string (so containing a double colon followed by a dot):

> aa:.bb

I get the following exception:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: created_at

In the logs the these are the sql queries:

```
with aa as input:
Author Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE (name LIKE 'aa%') ORDER BY created_at
Book Load (2.5ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE ("books".author_id IN (1,2,3)) ORDER BY id

with aa:.bb as input:
SELECT DISTINCT "authors".id FROM "authors" LEFT OUTER JOIN "books" ON "books"."author_id" = "authors"."id" WHERE (name LIKE 'aa:.bb%') ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 12 OFFSET 0
SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: created_at
```

It seems that with the aa:.bb input, an extra query is made to fetch the distinct author id_s.

I thought Rails would escape all the characters. Is this expected behaviour or a bug?

Best Regards,

Pieter

Answer (score 1):

The "ambiguous column" error usually happens when you use includes or joins and don't specify which table you're referring to:

```
"name LIKE :input"
```

Should be:

```
"authors.name LIKE :input"
```

Just "name" is ambiguous if your books table has a name column too.

Also: have a look at your development.log to see what the generated query looks like. This will show you if it's being escaped properly.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the 'created_at' column is causing the ambiguous exception. I understand your point, and that's a good tip, but it's really strange that is only happens when I input a word:.otherword as the search query

Comment: right, I missed that: the ambiguity is in the ORDER clause. You should look at your log to see the generated SQL query to be sure nothing funny is going on.

Comment: Andrew, I added the log output. It seems that with the aa:.bb input, an extra query is made to determine the distinct author_ids, to fetch the books. And that query raises the exception. It's no problem to order on 'houses.created_at' instead of just 'created_at', but it worries me that it looks like a :. could lead to a sql attack?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
.includes(:books)
```

with

```
.preload(:books)
```

This should force activerecord to use 2 queries instead of the join.

Answer (score 0):

Rails has 2 versions of includes: One which constructs a big query with joins (the 2nd of your 2 queries and thus more likely to result in ambiguous column references and one that avoids the joins in favour of a separate query per association.

Rails decides which strategy to used based on whether it thinks that your conditions, order etc refer to the included tables (since in that case the joins version is required). Where a condition is a string fragment that heuristic isn't very sophisticated - i seem to recall that it just scans the conditions for anything that might look like a column from another table (ie foo.bar) so having a literal of that form could fool it.

You can either qualify your column names so that it doesn't matter which includes strategy is used or you can use preload/eager_load instead of includes. These behave similarly to includes but force a specific include strategy rather than trying to guess which is most appropriate.